# how to sort an abstract class in java

Tags: java

I want to sort the customers according to their priority.
For example customers (Gold) have priority over customers (Silver).

```
public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>();       
        clients.add(new Or());
        clients.add(new Or());
        clients.add(new Or());
        clients.add(new Or());      
        clients.add(new Bronze());
        clients.add(new Bronze());
        clients.add(new Bronze());
        clients.add(new Argent());
        clients.add(new Argent());
        clients.add(new Argent());                  
    }       
}
```

Comment: Ok, but what is the problem? You've forgot to post a question.

Comment: ```Collections.sort(clients, new Comparator<Client>() {

   @Override
   public int compare(Client o1, Client o2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return o1.getPriorite() - o2.getPriorite();
   }

  }); ``` doesn't work

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], best would be the method of `Client.getPriorite()`

Comment: Don't put code in the comments, it is unreadable. Edit the question instead.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a good enough description of a problem. For example, similar code works for me just fine.

Comment: I do not know the method to adopt to sort customers with their priority with Comparator, Comparable

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I define a property priorite in each classe and I do this ``` private int priorite;

 public Or() {
  super();
  priorite = 1;
 }``` for Or's  class

Comment: OK, but you're thinking straight, but you need to make sure that this property is of course valid for each of the metals or alloys.

Comment: `clients.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Client::priorite));`  assuming the class `Client` has a method `int priorite()`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to define the priority to the system. For some humans that order may be self-evident, but others may price bronze higher than gold. Much more sturdy material.

So first you have to "explain" the order to the computer, because I can tell you that the computer doesn't have any idea about that at all. Generally you'd create a top class or interface `MetalOrAlloy` with a a `getValue` method or something similar. And preferably make the `MetalOrAlloy` implement or extend `Comparable` - *but only if you think that the current value of the material per gram is the main method of comparing alloys in your specific model of reality*.

For your system you're not really talking about metals or alloys, you are using gold/bronze/silver as an indicator of how much you value your clients. So you probably should use `CustomerPriority` as a base class, and a `getPriority` method to implement it. However, as you can see `getPriority` will always return the same value for `Gold` etc., so in that case you should probably use an `enum CustomerPriority` instead. Enums can also have read only properties - although their order is already evident.

Now the comparison becomes easy. Either you can compare them by just calling `Collections.sort` or you can call the longer `Collections.sort` with a `Comparator` that uses the property `value` and it's getter `getValue`.